# AWS DynamoDB-Lambda-Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am working with Temperature data sending. I am done with storing the data from DynamoDB.

Can anyone help me in getting the data from DynamoDB using AWS Lambda and send it to AWS S3 for quick sight?

Answer (score 1):

The Following code is a little snapshot of your requirement of getting from dynamodb through Lambda, for details check out this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write.html).

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create the DynamoDB service object
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

var params = {
  TableName: 'TABLE',
  Key: {
    'KEY_NAME': {N: '001'}
  },
  ProjectionExpression: 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME'
};

// Call DynamoDB to read the item from the table
ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data.Item);
  }
});
```

To Create a Data Set Using Amazon S3 Files, you can check out the this [doc](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-quicksight-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/create-a-data-set-s3.md)